# feedparser not installed. Using vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant

When running the vagrant file, I get the following error:

```
==> default:     import feedparser
==> default: ImportError: No module named feedparser
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I'm running OS X and at first I didn't have feedparser installed, but even after I installed it, I'm still getting the same error.
Somebody else set up the virtual box and vagrant config, but it's been working for a bunch of people except me. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have it installed and still not working, may be it's a path issue? Is the installation directory accessible to python?

Comment: There was a problem with the project I was using in the end I think. Just had to add it the file to the requirements file. Apparently you don't need to on Windows

Answer (score 0):

The requirements file was missing the package. Apparently a mac/windows issue...